# dictionary with list values as multi index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a multi index data frame from the following dictionaries :

`d = {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5], 'c': [7,8]}`

Tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')` with no luck

The keys should be the index first level and the value the second level of the multi index, the desired output would be :

```
a     1
      2
      3

b     4
      5

c     7
      8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) function from a Pandas Series

`pd.Series({'a': [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5], 'c': [7,8]}).explode()`

will return

```
a    1
a    2
a    3
b    4
b    5
c    7
c    8
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but it doesn't appear to be multi-index

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice use of `explode`. Can be annoying to get a MultiIndex since there's no `set_index` for Series, but adding `.to_frame().set_index(0, append=True)` gets it there.

Comment: Just for info, it's included from version 0.25 only.

Comment: To get the multi-index, you could use groupby(index, col1)

Answer (score 2):

with some help from `itertools`

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

idx = chain.from_iterable([zip_longest(k, v, fillvalue=k) for k,v in d.items()])
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(idx)
```

---

```
MultiIndex([('a', 1),
            ('a', 2),
            ('a', 3),
            ('b', 4),
            ('b', 5),
            ('c', 7),
            ('c', 8)],
           )
```